# tcpdump session issue in moving dump files out of current folder

Tags: dump, tcpdump, tshark

I would like to have a tcpdump script which dumps into files let's say every hour.
This I can achieve quite simply like this:
`tcpdump -i eth0 -G 3600 -w /tmp/files/<some-name>-%F-%H-%M-%S.pcap -Z root -z gzip`

I want to MOVE the "finished" files to s3 for which I'm using the rclone tool:

`rclone move /tmp/files remote:<s3 bucket name> --filter "- *.pcap"`

All runs fine apart from the fact that whenever I move some any of the `*pcap.gz` files the currently processed `*.pcap` **file size is enlarged with all the current session data** which makes the file pretty big.

Does this mean that I can't move out any of the files from the directory and have to restart the tcpdump command on regular basis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `tcpdump` command to add a capture filter that excludes the `rclone` traffic.  For example, assuming the remote IP address and TCP port number are 192.0.2.1 and 1234, respectively, apply a capture filter of "not (host 192.0.2.1 and tcp port 1234)" to exclude that traffic.